# Not able to redirect to app from Facebook Deep Linking URL Android

Tags: android

I am using the **ShareLinkContent** for sharing the event in Facebook. I am able to share the event to Facebook. But when I click on the post in Facebook feed section I am not able to open my android app. My ContentUrl is starting with **http**.

I have also added these lines in my Androidmanifest.xml file.

```
<data android:scheme="http" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
```

Comment: what is happening after clicking on the post?

Comment: have you added the action while firing the intent to open you deep link activity ?

Comment: have you added this code to your activity?                                                     Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();                                                                       Uri data = intent.getData();

Comment: Facebook is opening the given contentUrl in facebook default web view.

Comment: @Shruti thanks for your reply. Yes, I have added the codes you have mentioned. But still it is not working. any other solutions?

Comment: @Gautam, I have only added the <intent-filter> in my activity for redirection.

Comment: You need to add action too. If you are not adding the action it won't launch your activity with deep link but i don't know the reason behind it. You can give it a try.

Comment: @DebasishKumarDas you can test it using this link: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/app-ads-helper/

Comment: @Gautam Can you help me out for adding the action in the application? I am not sure where to add the action. But I have also added a action tag in the manifest code in my mentioned question.

Comment: @Shruti Thank you for the link. My application is able to receive deep links  as notification but when i am click on it, it is redirecting me to the Facebook app.

Comment: @DebasishKumarDas hope you have done facebook app settings correctly.https://developers.facebook.com/apps